# Azure Container Registry - 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-container-registry

I've been trying to push my docker images into  my Organization's Azure container registry but it's failing again and again with 401 error. I knew 401 error is with respect to authentication/authorization but I tried giving both "**Azure Service Principal ID**" which has contributor access to ACR and also "**Azure container registry admin access keys**". End result is same, getting 401 unauthorized error.

I presume "**Contributor**" role to ACR is more than enough to play around with it as it will have pretty much all privileges.

Also what confusing me more is getting 401 error even if I use **ACR Admin access keys** which I believe will have all sufficient privileges.

I tried to replicate the same scenario with my own azure account where I didn't get this error. I tried all possibilities and everything worked like charm in my account.

Am I missing something or going wrong anywhere?

Comment: Normally the role `AcrPush` is enough. How are you pushing your image ? through devops pipeline ?

Comment: Did you make sure to login to your container registry ```az acr login --name YourContainerRegistryName``` before pushing to container registry?

Comment: @Thomas Contributor role not suffice to push images? is AcrPush role also required?. I have set up a gitlab runner in AKE and through kaniko I'm trying to push the image to ACR. To my surprise, I did not get this error code when I push the images from my workstation through docker.

Comment: contributor is good also. Which SP have you been granted the contributor role ?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems wired. Generally, the admin access key has all the permission to manage the ACR. So it must have the ability to push the image into the ACR.

Usually, the possible reasons to get the authentication are here:

1. the service principal does not have enough permission from the ACR, this includes assigning a wrong role or a wrong scope. So you can check the role assignment if the role and the scope are right.
2. don't log in for the ACR with the right server URL, so this needs you to login again with the right server URL and the credential
3. the image name and the tag don't match the ACR that you have permission to push, so you need to check the image name if it's right. For example, `myacr.azurecr.io/image:tag`

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help. Have done 2nd and 3rd step and it worked. Could be the problem with the tag name.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I refreshed the passwords in the container registry, then picked a new password (primary or secondary) and editted it on the environment env `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD` of the app service